# all the characters in number plate are not recognized

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am extracting and segmenting the characters from number plate.I am facing problems with character recognition. I wish to extract the number and symbol and do not consider about alphabets.I am getting one character as output out of eight. After running this code, i got answer is'1'. I am appending matlab code for location and segmentation of the plate. I have given the input image for the reference.[image: untitled0][image: input image][image: untitled1][image: untitled2]`[image: untitled3]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VwdH.png) [[image: untitled4]][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZrUq.png)[[image: untitled5]][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYdpP.png)[[image: sign]][8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huR9y.png)Can anyone help me to rectify this error?

```
function [ImgPlate] = LocationPlate(I)

%% Cutting and resizing the original image %%
% I=imread('2222.jpg');
% figure,imshow(I);

[rows columns]=size(I);
columns=columns/3;
xmin=round(0.20*rows);
ymin=round(0.20*columns);
width=round((0.85*columns)-(0.10*columns));
height=round((0.85*rows)-(0.15*rows));
Io=imcrop(I,[xmin ymin width height]);
Io=imresize(Io,[480 640]);
Io=rgb2gray(Io);
Io=imadjust(Io);

 %% Image processing to focus the area of number plate %%
 %% Smooth edges and contours to delete characters.

 se=strel('rectangle',[6 30]);

    Ic=imclose(Io,se);
    Ic=imadjust(Ic);
    tophat=Ic-Io;
    Ibw=(tophat>85);

 %% Remove the related elements with fewer than 70 pixels %%
 %% Remove objects that are not plate %%

 plate= bwlabel(Ibw,4);
 obj= max(max(plate));
 dim1 = regionprops(plate, 'area')';

    dim=[dim1.Area];
    dim(find(dim<70))=0;

for i=1:obj


index=find(plate==i);
if dim(i)==0
    plate(index)=0;

else
    plate(index)=1;
end

end


CC=bwconncomp(plate);
P=regionprops(CC,'all');
[rp cp]=size(plate);


 for i=1:CC.NumObjects


    if P(i).MajorAxisLength>(2*cp/3)
    plate(P(i).PixelIdxList(:,1))=0;
    end

  end

 %% Remove objects that are not candidates for plate %%

 se3=strel('rectangle',[30 70]);
 r2=imclose(plate,se3);

 se2=strel('rectangle',[5 30]);
 r=imdilate(r2,se2);


    CC=bwconncomp(r);
    P=regionprops(CC,'all');

 for i=1:CC.NumObjects


    if P(i).MajorAxisLength>(2*cp/3)
    r(P(i).PixelIdxList(:,1))=0;

    end

    end

 %% select the largest connected component after preprocessing, the
    %%plate

 plate1= bwlabel(r,4);
 dim2= regionprops(plate1, 'area')';

    dim1=[dim2.Area];
    f=max(dim1);
    indMax=find(dim1==f);
    plate1(find(plate1~=indMax))=0;

 %% cutting of original image %%

 [cuty, cutx] = find( plate1 > 0);
 up = min(cuty);

    down = max(cuty);
    left = min(cutx);
    right = max(cutx);
    img_cut_v = Io(up:down,:,:);
    img_cut_h = img_cut_v(:,left:right,:);

    ImgPlate = img_cut_h;

    %% different mask for location plate %%


    [r c]=size(ImgPlate);


    if r<25 || r>65

    [rows columns]=size(I);
    columns=columns/3;
    xmin=round(0.20*rows);
    ymin=round(0.20*columns);
    width=round((0.85*columns)-(0.10*columns));
    height=round((0.85*rows)-(0.15*rows));
    Io=imcrop(I,[xmin ymin width height]);
    Io=imresize(Io,[480 640]);
    Io=rgb2gray(Io);
    Io=imadjust(Io);

    se=strel('rectangle',[6 30]);
    Ic=imclose(Io,se);
    Ic=imadjust(Ic);
    tophat=Ic-Io;
    Ibw1=(tophat>85);
    mask=zeros(480,640);
    for i=40:370
    for j=40:575
    mask(i,j)=1;
    end
    end


    Ibw=Ibw1 & im2bw(mask);
    plate= bwlabel(Ibw,4);
    obj= max(max(plate));
    dim1 = regionprops(plate, 'area')';
    dim=[dim1.Area];
    dim(find(dim<70))=0;


    for i=1:obj
    index=find(plate==i);
    if dim(i)==0
    plate(index)=0;

    else
    plate(index)=1;

    end
    end


    CC=bwconncomp(plate);
    P=regionprops(CC,'all');
    [rp cp]=size(plate);


    for i=1:CC.NumObjects
    if P(i).MajorAxisLength>(cp/3)
    plate(P(i).PixelIdxList(:,1))=0;

    end
    end


    se3=strel('rectangle',[30 70])



    r2=imclose(plate,se3);
    se2=strel('rectangle',[5 30]);
    r=imdilate(r2,se2);


    plate1= bwlabel(r,4);
    dim2= regionprops(plate1, 'area')';
    dim1=[dim2.Area];
    f=max(dim1);
    indMax=find(dim1==f);
    plate1(find(plate1~=indMax))=0;

    [cuty, cutx] = find( plate1 > 0);

    up = min(cuty);
    down = max(cuty);
    left = min(cutx);
    right = max(cutx);
    img_cut_v = Io(up:down,:,:);
    img_cut_h = img_cut_v(:,left:right,:);
    ImgPlate = img_cut_h;

    end

    %% Representation %%


    % figure(1);
    % imshow(I);
    % subplot(2,2,1);imshow(I);
    % subplot(2,2,2);imshow(Ic);% subplot(2,2,3);imshow(plate);
    % subplot(2,2,4);imshow(plate1);


    figure(2);  imshow(img_cut_h);title('output location plate');
    end
function [Objects,ImgChar]=Segmentation(ImgPlate)

    %% Binarize the image %%
    level = graythresh(ImgPlate);
    Ibw =(im2bw(ImgPlate,level));


    %% Select the orientation of the largest object in the image.
    %% Turn this angle at the picture.
    %% Plate cutting to segment the characters that compose %%


    Fl=bwlabel(Ibw);
    Statsbf=regionprops(Fl,'all');
    Flmax=find([Statsbf.Area]==max([Statsbf.Area]));
    angle=Statsbf(Flmax).Orientation;
    F2=imrotate(Fl,-angle);
    L=bwlabel(F2);
    Statsbf=regionprops(L,'all');
    maxi=find([Statsbf.Area]==max([Statsbf.Area]));
    BB=Statsbf(maxi).BoundingBox;
    F2=imcrop(F2,[BB(1,1) BB(1,2) BB(1,3) BB(1,4)]);
% figure,imshow(F2);

    %% First three and last three rows to zero.
    %% First two and last two columns to zero.
    %% So remove connectivity between characters and background %%
    %% Remove small impurities %%


    L4=not(F2);
    [r c]=size(L4);
    L4(1,:)=0;
    L4(2,:)=0;
    L4(3,:)=0;
    L4(r,:)=0;
    L4(r-1,:)=0;
    L4(r-2,:)=0;
    L4(:,1)=0;
    L4(:,2)=0;
    L4(:,c)=0;
    L4(:,c-1)=0;


    L4b=bwlabel(L4);
    Stats3=regionprops(L4b,'all');
    sarea3=[Stats3.Area];
    G=find(sarea3<70);


    for cv=1:length(G)
    G1=find(L4b==G(cv));
    L4(G1)=0;

    end
    [r c]=size(L4);
    CC=bwconncomp(L4);
    L=bwlabel(L4);
    ind2=max(L(:,c-2));
    P=regionprops(CC,'all');

    %% Remove objects smaller and larger than a character %%


    i=1;
    if  (max(P(i,1).PixelList(:,1))-min(P(i,1).PixelList(:,1)))<(c/13)
             L4(CC.PixelIdxList{1,i})=0;
    end

    for i=1:CC.NumObjects


    if (max(P(i,1).PixelList(:,1))-min(P(i,1).PixelList(:,1)))>(2*c/3)
         L4(CC.PixelIdxList{1,i})=0;

    end

    if (max(P(i,1).PixelList(:,2))-min(P(i,1).PixelList(:,2)))<(r/3)

       L4(CC.PixelIdxList{1,i})=0;
    end


    if (max(P(i,1).PixelList(:,1))-min(P(i,1).PixelList(:,1)))<(c/8)
        L4(find(L==ind2))=0;

    end

    end


    L4=imclose(L4,strel('disk',1));
    L4=imopen(L4,strel('disk',1));
%   figure(4);
    imshow(L4);
    L4b=bwlabel(L4);
    Stats3b=regionprops(L4b,'all');

    N=length(Stats3b);


    while N>8
    L4=imdilate(L4,strel('disk',1));
    L4b=bwlabel(L4);
    Stats3b=regionprops(L4b,'all');
    N=length(Stats3b);

    end


    L4b=bwlabel(L4);
    Stats3b=regionprops(L4b,'all');
    ImgChar=zeros(100,100,N);

 %% Dividing characters which are connected %%
 %% Remove objects that have been listed as characters but are not%
 %% Show every character in the correct position %%


    cont=0;
    cont1=0;

 for i=1:N

    [r1 c1]=size(Stats3b(i,1).Image);


    if c1>round(c/6)
    cont1=cont;
    Stats3b(i,1).Image(:,round(c1/2))=0;
    L5=Stats3b(i,1).Image;
    CC=bwconncomp(L5);
    CC1=regionprops(CC,'all');

    for j=1:CC.NumObjects
    [r2 c2]=size(CC1(j,1).Image);
    if c2>round(c/7)

    CC1(j,1).Image(:,round(c2/2))=0;
    L6=CC1(j,1).Image;
    LL=bwconncomp(L6);
    CC2=regionprops(LL,'all');
    for k=1:LL.NumObjects

    CC2(k).Image=imresize(CC2(k).Image, [100 100]);
    figure;imshow((CC2(k).Image))
    ImgChar(:,:,i+cont1)=not(CC2(k).Image);
    cont1=cont1+1;
    end
    cont=cont+1;
    else

    CC1(j).Image=imresize(CC1(j).Image, [100 100]);

    figure;imshow((CC1(j).Image))
    ImgChar(:,:,i+cont1)=not(CC1(j).Image);
    cont1=cont1+1;
    end
    end

    cont=cont+1;


    else
    Stats3b(i).Image=imresize(Stats3b(i).Image, [100 100]);
    figure;imshow((Stats3b(i).Image));


    if cont~=0
    ImgChar(:,:,i+cont)=not(Stats3b(i).Image);
    else
    ImgChar(:,:,i)=not(Stats3b(i).Image);

    end
end
end

 %% Remove spurious %%

 [x, y, Objects]=size(ImgChar);
end

function [strPlate] = Recognition(I)
    I=imread('2222.jpg');
    [ImgPlate] = LocationPlate(I);
    [Objects,ImgChar]=Segmentation(ImgPlate);
    N=struct('Image',{});
    numbers={'0','1','2','3','4','5','sign'};
    N(1).Image=imresize(im2bw(uint8(imread('untitled0.bmp'))),[100 100]);
    N(2).Image=imresize(im2bw(uint8(imread('untitled1.bmp'))),[100 100]);
    N(3).Image=imresize(im2bw(uint8(imread('untitled2.bmp'))),[100 100]);
    N(4).Image=imresize(im2bw(uint8(imread('untitled3.bmp'))),[100 100]);
    N(5).Image=imresize(im2bw(uint8(imread('untitled4.bmp'))),[100 100]);
    N(6).Image=imresize(im2bw(uint8(imread('untitled5.bmp'))),[100 100]);
    N(7).Image=imresize(im2bw(uint8(imread('sign.jpg'))),[100 100]);
    if Objects==8
       strPlate=[];
         for i=1:Objects
         char=ImgChar(:,:,i);
            if  (i==2)||(i==3)||(i==4) || (i==5) || (i==6)||(i==7) ||(i==8)
                list_corr=[];
                for j=1:7
                    corr=corr2(N(j).Image,char);
                   list_corr=[list_corr corr];
               end
            f=max(list_corr);
            maxcorr=find(list_corr==f);
            strPlate=[strPlate numbers(maxcorr)];
         end
      end
    end
 end
```

Comment: @hnefatl. Thank you i incorporated the suggestion in the edited question.

Comment: This code is not a [mcve]

Comment: @AnderBiguri As a beginner in matlab i tired as much as possible. I clearly mentioned, i will provide the complete code on demand. Do you need the code for segmentation?

Comment: You have code that doesn't work and want help to fix the code. It is quite straightforward to realise that unless you show the entirety of the code, on its most minimal (short!!) form, we can not help, as we are unable to run it. Unless we can see in our computer the same thing as you do, there is no way we can help. It has to be runnable, but also the shortest possible. Ultimately, if you want help, you need to put something from your side.

Comment: To be more clear, this question breaks StackOverflow rules because: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].*

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have edited the question by including the code for location and segmentation. Please provide your suggestion to recognize the all the characters.

Comment: You still do not fill the requirements. Yes, now I can run the code. So what's the problem with it? What do you expect? When I run the code, I get an image of a plate.

Comment: Thanks AnderBiguri. After running segmentation code you can get figures for segmented characters i.e. arabic letter,PwD sign followed by numbers. I saved the PwD sign and numbers as reference to do recognition task.  But after running recognition function, I got only one character as output but expected characters are 7. Can you run the recognition function code?

Comment: Apologies, but I don't have the time to be explaining every time why you are not showing the code we need to run. Good luck

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I have given code for functions  namely, location,segmentation and recognition in the question. Please review the coding part and suggest the way forward.

Comment: where you expect to find the output? what are the parameters names? I think if you write the error related code will be much easier to understand for us than trying to understand this long code

Comment: How we can reach to the images in Recognition() function ?!

Comment: The error happening with Recognition function given in the last part of coding. The strplate is the output variable. but The function is not recognizing all the characters recognises only one.

Comment: @Mohammadnagdawi i will attach the images, thank you.

Comment: @Mohammadnagdawi, I attached the images in the edited question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find you compare `char` image with the default value of `ImgChar` (zeros). I discovered this by add `imshow(char)` as you can see in the below code.

```
 for i=1:Objects
        char=ImgChar(:,:,i);
        if  (i==2)||(i==3)||(i==4) || (i==5) || (i==6)||(i==7) ||(i==8)
            list_corr=[];
            for j=1:6
                corr=corr2(N(j).Image,char);
                list_corr=[list_corr corr];
            end
            close all
            figure;imshow(char)
            f=max(list_corr);
            maxcorr=find(list_corr==f);
            strPlate=[strPlate numbers(maxcorr)];
        end
    end
```

To correct the above error, I modified the below code to store images in `ImgChar`. this line maybe not correct but I believe my answer may help you.

```
Stats3b(i).Image=imresize(Stats3b(i).Image, [100 100]);
        figure;
        imshow((Stats3b(i).Image));

        ImgChar(:,:,i) = Stats3b(i).Image;% added

        if cont~=0

        else
            ImgChar(:,:,i)=not(Stats3b(i).Image);

        end
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the segmentation coding from                       if cont~=0
else  to                                                                                                
 if cont~=0
 ImgChar(:,:,i+cont)=not(Stats3b(i).Image);else to include

Comment: Thank you very much for coding insights, it helped me lot. I have done little changes in the segmentation coding to store the images                                                                                         if cont~=0
else  to                                                                                                
 if cont~=0
 ImgChar(:,:,i+cont)=not(Stats3b(i).Image);else     However, the recognised the characters are wrong. Can you please suggest the solution?

Comment: Try to add more samples for each digit and/or use grayscale instead of binary images with corr2?

Comment: @Mohammed Thank you so much i done it for particular image!!!!! I will try with group of images/video.

Comment: you are welcome. don't forget to accept my answer if your problem solved.